# Well-ordered commutative semirings

Tags: well-orders, semiring

I am interested in the characterization of the most important types of numbers from an axiomatic viewpoint. For example, every complete ordered field is isomorphic to the field of real numbers. In this sense, being a complete ordered field characterizes the real numbers. I am now looking at the much simpler set of positive integers. It is a well-ordered commutative semiring. Does this property characterize them? In other words,
are there any well-ordered commutative semirings other than the positive integers?

Comment: I could be missing something as I haven't really studied semirings, but it seems $\omega + 1$ could be given the structure of a commutative semiring if you define $$\omega + x = \omega, \\ \omega \cdot 0 = 0 \\ x > 0 \implies \omega \cdot x = \omega$$

Comment: Actually after posting the question I had the thought that since every set can be well-ordered, being just a well-ordered commutative semiring is likely not enough to characterize the positive integers. What about a countable, well-ordered commutative semiring?

Comment: That's no better - just consider any other countable commutative semiring. You want to add a condition that the well-ordering respects the algebraic structure (in the manner of **[ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)** or **[ordered groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group)**). To avoid "the naturals with infinity" (a la @BrianMoehring's comment above) you'll also want to add something like a cancellativity condition.

Comment: But even that's not going to be enough: consider e.g. the set of polynomials in a single variable with all coefficients nonnegative integers, ordered by (say) comparison at infinity ($f<g$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)-f(x)>0$). This is a commutative well-ordered fully-cancellative semiring, but is very far from $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber So if I understand well, every countable, commutative, well-ordered semiring with $x<y$ iff $a+x<a+y$ for all $a$ is isomorphic to the positive integers?

Comment: @Math101 No, see my most recent comment (or my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not nearly enough for an exact characterization. A good counterexample to consider is the set $\mathbb{N}[x]$ of polynomials in a single variable with nonnegative integer coefficients, with addition and multiplication given in the obvious way and ordered by setting $$f<g\quad\iff\quad f(x)<g(x)\mbox{ for all sufficiently large $x$}.$$ This is a countable commutative well-ordered semiring; moreover, the ordering "plays nicely" with the algebraic structure (a la [ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) or [ordered groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group)) and we have a cancellation property (which distinguishes this from [Brian Moehring's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243812/well-ordered-commutative-semirings/4243822#comment8819849_4243812) above).

---

That said, here are a couple characterizations which do work:

- $(\mathbb{N};0,1,+,\times,<)$ is the unique well-ordered commutative unital semiring satisfying the **"difference condition"** that for each $x,y$ there is some $z$ such that either $x+z=y$ or $y+z=x$.
- $(\mathbb{N};0,1,+,\times,<)$ is the unique well-ordered commutative unital semiring in which every nonzero element has a **predecessor**.
- $(\mathbb{N};0,1,+,\times)$ is the **initial object** in the category of unital semirings (and we can add ordering to this if we want).

Comment: I see. So being countable plays no role? This would mean that any such system must be countable.

Comment: @Math101 Yes, in this sort of context countability is generally an immediate consequence of other conditions; by itself it doesn't do a whole ton (and in fact it's worth noting that in a technical sense this [can be made precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem)).

Comment: So it seems that characterizing the positive integers is a lot harder than characterizing the reals.

Comment: @Math101 That's a subjective point, but personally I don't think so. The three characterizations I give are pretty elementary in my opinion; the only complicated aspect in the first two is the "well-ordered" bit, but I don't think that's any more complicated than the completeness property needed to characterize the reals, and I think initiality is strictly less complicated than completeness.

Comment: @Math101 And things get even nicer if we look at $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the unique ordered *ring* whose positive elements are well-ordered.

Comment: I see your point. Let's say that the characterization of the positive integers uses notions that a typical undergraduate student would find less familiar than the completeness axiom for the reals. Would you know where I could find a proof that those properties characterize $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Curious.  In retrospect, I'm not even sure if my example should count, since the algebraic structure only respects $\leq$ and not $<$.  Do you know if there's a consensus on a theory of ordered semirings/monoids without the cancellative property to tell whether respecting only $\leq$ is at all interesting?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No idea, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough.  It was a shot in the dark.  Thanks for the illustrative example all the same.

Comment: @Noah Schweber Thanks for the helpful example. To address a point of convention and terminology, am I right in understanding that just as "ordered semiring" includes the fact that the order respects the algebraic structure, the same is true of "well-ordered semiring"? I would be interested in knowing some references for these characterization results.